# Is the eslint rule react/no-unescaped-entities necessary for React Native?

Tags: react-native, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

We are using the Airbnb code style guide with eslint in our React Native app. Since React Native does not use HTML, is the rule `react/no-unescaped-entities` necessary?

The rule is forcing me to use:

```
<Text>{`"${this.state.quote}"`}</Text>
```

instead of:

```
<Text>"{this.state.quote}"</Text>
```

Comment: @AndrewLi They produce exactly the same thing in the iOS simulator

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected. Oddly, Babel does transpile in a way where the original reference is used... I wouldn't count on it in terms of readability though

Answer (score 0):

It is not required unless You want to contribute to some component that use the same code style it is considered best practice